How i can use Dicord event ID to ping it in discord chanel?
<@ID> - ping user
<#ID> - ping chanel
<@&ID> - ping role
?   - ping event?
What else can be pinged and how?
find information in internet) its dont help
I need help, I can't find any information about this, and there is nowhere else to ask

Since events are tied to the invitation system of Discord, as in they are accessible by using a discord.gg url. Because of this (and it is very similar to how guilds are "mentioned", they only way to "ping" them is to paste the URL of the event which looks something like this:
https://discord.gg/XXXXXXXX?event=1234567891234567890

What it will display is a custom embed that houses all of the details about the event.
This is the current and only way to share/mention/ping/display a scheduled event inside a channel. Other than that they are only shown in the "Events" section at the top of the channel list in the guild.
More information about scheduled events can be found here.
